# How do I compile a PowerShell script so that it is shown as safe by antivirus?

Tags: powershell

I want to release a program written as a script in PowerShell (*.PS1) but get on all computers after compiling the file with PS2EXE a notification that it is unsecure and could be a Trojan. The script is a kind of image editing program.

Here is the scan: [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/fa3ff46adb601edefd179a2cdee9b23b0f9672f2b34a7b8eea785ed4fb9bb58e/detection)

How do I compile the file so that it is shown as safe by antivirus?
Should I use another program to compile it?

Comment: What does the script do? Why not distribute it as a Powershell script instead?

Comment: The script is a kind of image editing program. I want the program to look as a normal program and easy to start. Would you release your, e.g. C# project repository?

Comment: You could put a shortcut on the user's desktop that launches `powershell.exe -File imageEditor.ps1`

Comment: That is not a bad idea but still not the solution. I do not want to let the user be able to edit the script.

Comment: If that was the main concern then PowerShell was not the best language to code your program, C# would have been the better option. If your concern is that the user should not modify the code then you could implement a hash check to see if the program should run or not and still that would be easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

PS2EXE explicitly says that the compilation is not secure - anyone can extract the files with the correct switch. The only reason to use it is for convenience.

Some people have used it to compile malware, which is why AV solutions are picking it up.

Firstly:

> Report it as a false positive to your AV supplier

Secondly:

> Whitelist the exe in your antivirus solution - most allow you to whitleist the md5 checksum which will enable it to be run safely wihtout being quarantined/disabled.

As above, you only other option is to distribute it as a normal script. You can also sign the script so that it is not possible to edit and run without re-signing it. This is how scripts are distributed on our domain. It's not foolproof but it suffices.